# SqlDataReader parameter not working

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, parameter-passing, sqldatareader

I have a windows form that I am asking a user to enter a pcname in textbox1 and then trying to use `SqlDataReader` to the read from the database to get the pc ipaddress and then map the pc drive to my local pc.

But for some reason when I use the textbox within the SQL parameter it's not working. But when I replace the `textbox1.text` with the actual pcname it works fine. Hopefully someone can help me find out why the parameter isn't working correctly.

Here is my code:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string results = "";

    using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(@"***removed connection string***"))
    {
        cs.Open();

        string query = "select stationipaddress from station where stationname = @StationName";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cs))
        {
            // Add the parameter and set its value -- 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StationName", textBox1.Text);

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    label3.Text = dr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString();
                    results = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show(results);
                }

                string myvar = string.Format(@"use S: \\" + label3.Text + "\\c$\logs 0A36303 /user:admin", label3.Text);

                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = (myvar);
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.Start();
```

Comment: Please lern to format your questions properly. It shows some effort to take that few minutes.

Comment: Get rid of the Single quotes around '@StationName'. With them there it makes it a the string literal @StationName rather than a parameter.

Comment: also besides the single quotes as Conrad Frix said you could replace the `using(SqlDataReader)` with a simple 'SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()' to get rid of the inner using.

Comment: I've updated the code but it still isn't working, does it look correct?

Comment: If you're only returning a single column from a single row, you can replace the `ExecuteReader` with `ExecuteScalar`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Comment: Also, are you getting an error, or is it just not returning any rows?

Comment: try to use breakpoints, and see whats happening on the parameter row

Comment: It's not even populating a messagebox. it just sits there.

Comment: Which would suggest it's not returning any rows.

Comment: shouldn't the messagbox just be blank>? If I take the @StationName out of the query and just insert the station name it populates the messageboxes fine

Comment: No, because if there are no rows returned, `dr.Read()` will never return `true`, and your code will never enter the `while` loop.

Comment: @FlorisPrijt - Why get rid of the inner using?  The SqlDataReader needs to be disposed too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you separate you code in different lines, one to set up your parameter, and one to add it, you can better see where the problem is.
Something like this:

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@StationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, textBox1.Text.length);
param1.Value = textBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
```

at least is easier to see what is going on on the debugger.

Comment: When I put the stationname in the query like this: 'stationname' it works but doesn't with a parameter, does this have something to do with it?

Comment: When using mssql you use single quotes in a sql statement to denote a string. In c# single quotes denote char type not a string.