# C# SQL Query and apostrophe's

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SqlDataReader parameter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647964/sqldatareader-parameter-not-working)

I am trying to get a pc name from a textbox to a sql parameter in a windows form application.
It works fine when I input the parameter like the following.

```
                string query = @"select stationipaddress from station where stationname = @Name";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cs))
            {


               SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@Name";
                param.Value = "demo";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        label3.Text = dr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString();
                        results = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(results);
                    }
```

But Then it does nothing when I try and get the data from the textbox.

```
 string query = @"select stationipaddress from station where stationname = @Name";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cs))
            {


                  SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@Name";
                param.Value = textBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        label3.Text = dr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString();
                        results = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(results);
                    }
```

Comment: What is the actual behavior you are seeing?

Comment: What is the error/problem with the above?

Comment: Please don't re-post the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647964/sqldatareader-parameter-not-working

Comment: I have updated my code above

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving out all of your MessageBox Operations until after you've retrieved your results from the database.  Add your results to a Strongly typed list and then display the message accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try double apostrophes like '' -> "John's" --> "John''s"

Comment: I did this: ''@StationName'' and it said incorrect syntax near '@StationName'

Comment: add the entire exception in your question.

Answer (score 0):

After you call `AddWithValue` set the `DbType` of your parameter. That should quote your string properly.

```
cmd.Parameters["@StationName"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
```

EDIT: Sorry, I meant to specify SqlDbType

Comment: When I do that I get the following error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: I have updated my code above

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you strip out the apostrophies i.e.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StationName", textBox1.Text.Replace("'","")
```

If the database field values in StationName contain apostrophies then you will have to change your SQL statement to this:

```
select stationipaddress from station where replace(stationname,CHAR(39),'') = @StationName
```

Comment: what should the query say just @StationName or '@StationName'?

Comment: I don't understand the original question.  Are the apostrophes is the database field (Station.StationName) or are they in the textbox (textbox1.text) or are they in both?

Comment: In order to get results back from the db it has to be like: where stationname = 'stationname', thats why I can't get any results back

Comment: In that case change your SQL statement to: select stationipaddress from station where StationName = char(39) + @StationName + char(39)